# Python Port Scanner with Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to create a port scanner in Python. I got the scanner going but it takes forty five minutes to print results. I started to institute threading however I can't figure out how to put different ranges into the script. I started to go to creating a global variable and try to pass that along in each thread. Unfortunately it's not working correctly and I am getting an invalid syntax error. Below is the code.

```
import socket
import os
import sys
from threading import Thread

server = raw_input("Please enter a server name ")

def portConnect():

    global num 

    try:
        serv_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server) # connects to server through try
        print "Please wait, scanning remote host", serv_ip

        for port in range(num):
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            connect =  sock.connect_ex((serv_ip, port))
            if connect == 0:
                print "Port {}: Open".format(port)
        sock.close()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print """
        I can't find that server, idiot! Try again
        """ 
        sys.exit()          

for i in range(1):
    t = Thread(target=portConnect,(num=100))
    t.start()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the multiprocessing page https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html and in particular at `Pool` and `Process` which might be the best fit for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread expects `args=` as tuple and it sends it as arguments to function

This way you send `100` as first argument (`num`) to `portConnect()`

```
 def portConnect(num):
     print(num)
     # code

 t = Thread(target=portConnect, args=(100,) )
```

To send range you need two arguments

```
def portConnect(from_, to_):
    print(from_, to_)
    for port in range(from_, to_):
        # ...

size = 20
for i in range(1, 100, size):
    t = Thread(target=portConnect, args=(i, i+size))
    t.start()
```

---

BTW: module [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) lets you send single packet so it is used for portscanning, sniffing, etc.

You can do more with special tools like `nmap` (GUI wrapper: [Zenmap](https://nmap.org/zenmap/)) or [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/)

You may try to use `nmap` in Python: [python-nmap : nmap from python](http://xael.org/pages/python-nmap-en.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this really easily using nmap.

`nmap -p- <some_host>`

Comment: Yes I could however I'm trying to create my own port scanner.